# Swipe event doesn't work on firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox

I am having a problem with jQuery Mobile and Firefox.
The problem is that a swipe event in Firefox doesn't work. Here is the code I am using (you have swipe over an image):

```
$('#slider_Backgrounds').on("swipeleft",sliderControlRight);
```

I hope someone can help me with making this code also work in FireFox.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Hope this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y4am3sqw/) helps you out,

HTML:

```
<div class="slider_Backgrounds">

</div>
<div class="slider_Backgrounds">

</div>
<div class="slider_Backgrounds">

</div>
<div class="slider_Backgrounds">

</div>
```

JQuery:

```
 $(document).on("swipeleft",'.slider_Backgrounds',sliderControlRight);    

 function sliderControlRight(){
   $(this).hide();
   alert(1232);
 }
```

Check [api reference](https://api.jquerymobile.com/swipeleft/) for more options and to learn better use.